# как реализовать click в библиотеке arsenic

Tags: python, asyncio

Перехожу с selenium в arsenic и возникла ошибка с кликом, если в selenium это работало, то в arsenic, как я понял, клик работает по-другому, и, соответственно, ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'click'.

Как реализовать клик в arsenic?

```py
import asyncio
from arsenic import *

async def flashscore():
    service = services.Chromedriver(binary="./chromedriver.exe")
    browser = browsers.Chrome()
    async with get_session(service, browser) as session:
        await session.get("https://www.flashscore.com")
        accept = session.wait_for_element(0.1, "#onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(flashscore())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте await:

```
accept = await session.wait_for_element(0.1, "#onetrust-accept-btn-handler") 
await accept.click()
```

Comment: Не работает. ошибка RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Element.click' was never awaited

Comment: @Владислав Гончаров
 дописал еще один await в ответ, попробуйте так

Comment: К сожалению ничего не получается. Уже даже chromedriver переустановил...